# How to run queries on standby postgres server when hot_standby_feedback is on Postgres 12

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to move reporting data off our master server onto the slave for postgres 12.

I understand that hot_standby_feedback being on allows this but is there any other parameters I need to be aware of?

There are 2 other postgres features that can be tweaked.

max_standby_archive_delay

max_standby_streaming_delay

They are currently set at the default 30 seconds.

We initially ran a reporting query which takes on average of 15 minutes on our master server, its basically a huge SELECT statement (reading data).

When running it direct via psql the query runs fine on the slave (with the max_standby_archive_delay set at 30s along with the max_standby_streaming_delay also set at 30s)

But if its run via a crontab we get the following error:

```
ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
DETAIL:  User was holding shared buffer pin for too long
```

Why would this be the case?

I can look to set those 2 values I mentioned above to 20minutes and see but just curious.

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: How many times did you repeat this in each environment, and did you get the same result every one of those times?

Comment: Are you saying you did turn hot_standby_feedback on and this happened anyway, or are you asking whether turning hot_standby_feedback on would prevent this from happening?

Comment: @jjanes I ran the day before and it ran fine (ran around evening time where environment were less busy) then ran the morning after where environment is busier and it failed after the 30 second timeout. With the holding shared buffer pin for too long message. Hot_standby_feedback was on for both times.

Answer (score 1):

There is no per-lock grace period for query cancellation.  Once the replay process is more than 30 seconds behind, then every blocker gets shot on sight, even if the blockage would have lasted only microseconds, and even if the big-picture reason for being behind has nothing to do with that blocker.

The buffer pin conflicts are not avoided by the feedback.  Once a tuple is old enough to be removed (under whatever feedback is in effect), doing the removal requires a buffer clean-up lock on the block it is going to be removed from, and that locks needs to be taken in the here and now, regardless of the age of the tuple being removed.  And once taken on the master, it *has* to be replayed on the replica--no conditionality is possible.

So this is the mostly likely scenario--the replay is already behind when the conflict is spotted.  Then your options are to figure out why it is behind and fix that bottleneck, increase the max_standby_*_delay so it is rarely ever behind by that new amount, or learn to live with occasional cancellations.

It is also possible that you just have a long lived buffer pin on the replica which is single-handedly holding the replay back by 30 seconds, but I think that that is unlikely.  I would just discount this possibility unless you find the system is never behind by 30 seconds except immediately before the cancellation.

Another solution may be to hack the system to add a per-lock grace period for buffer pins, since those are usually help only briefly.  Or, just upscale the master and stop trying to offload the work to the replica.

As for the cron job, you can't say much based on a sample size of 2.  You rolled a die twice and got different results, there is no valid lesson to be learned from that.

Answer (score 0):

The query is canceled because of replication conflicts, as the message says. Turning on `hot_standby_feedback` won't remove all replication conflicts (and it may cause bloat on the primary server).

You have two choices:

- raise `max_standby_streaming_delay` on the standby
- repeat the query until you get it to run without an error

Comment: interestingly running the query yesterday evening ran just fine yet running the exact same query via cron this morning (likely busier) failed after the 30 seconds.... was just curious as whether running via Cron makes any difference at all (it still runs as the PG user). Will also look at increasing the max_standby_streaming_delay to a suitable time, is it worth also increasing the max_standby_archive_delay or leave as is?

Comment: It is just the luck of the draw: sometimes there is a conflict, sometimes there isn't. If you have a `restore_command`, raising `max_standby_archive_delay` as well makes sense.